# guice - select different providers while running

Tags: osgi, guice

I want to change a provider I'm using at runtime without having to stop the JVM.  For example, this isn't exactly what I'm trying to do, but the idea is the same: Say, I want to switch from Amazon S3 to Google Cloud storage in the middle of a running application.

Is that something I can do within guice?

I would have to have all jars available at runtime and configure all modules at startup.  Then, later once the application is started, I'd have to use a provider that can determine which instance to inject @ startup and later on when it changes.

Or, would it be better just to restart the application after updating a configuration and the system would then proceed with that configuration and if it needs to change, the application would again need to be restarted.

Would OSGI help here?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need anything extra: Guice can do it out-of-the-box. But... you'll have to use [`Provider`s](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InjectingProviders) instead of the direct instance.

**In your module**

```
bind(Cloud.class)
  .annotatedWith(Names.named("google"))
  .to(GoogleCloud.class);
bind(Cloud.class)
  .annotatedWith(Names.named("amazon"))
  .to(AmazonCloud.class);
bind(Cloud.class)
  .toProvider(SwitchingCloudProvider.class);
```

**Somewhere**

```
class SwitchingCloudProvider implements Provider<Cloud> {
  @Inject @Named("google") Provider<Cloud> googleCloudProvider;
  @Inject @Named("amazon") Provider<Cloud> amazonCloudProvider;
  @Inject Configuration configuration;        // used as your switch "commander"
  public Cloud get() {
    switch(configuration.getCloudName()) {
      case "google": return googleCloudProvider.get();
      case "amazon": return amazonCloudProvider.get();
      default: 
        // Whatever you want, usually an exception.
    }
  }
}
```

**Or in a provider method in your module**

```
@Provides
Cloud provideCloud(
    @Named("google") Provider<Cloud> googleCloudProvider,
    @Named("amazon") Provider<Cloud> amazonCloudProvider,
    Configuration configuration) {
  switch(configuration.getCloudName()) {
    case "google": return googleCloudProvider.get();
    case "amazon": return amazonCloudProvider.get();
    default: 
      // Whatever you want, usually an exception.
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
class Foo {
  @Inject Provider<Cloud> cloudProvider; // Do NOT inject Cloud directly or you won't get the changes as they come up.
  public void bar() {
    Cloud cloud = cloudProvider.get();
    // use cloud
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  Is this a good idea?  I think the way I would implement it is to avoid limiting myself to just 2 or 3, etc.  I think I could use multibinder here to find every implementation, then determine which one I want by selecting the right one from the list that matches the configuration (or throwing an exception at that point).

Comment: @WalterWhite Yes, it's a good idea, and using multibinding here is good as well. Given that nothing in the question allowed me to evaluate your level in Guice, I didn't think it would be best to bring it up, but yes, Multibinding is totally the best tool if you can go that far now. I will only insist here that you need to use `Provider`s to avoid surprises if one of the cloud has a non-singleton scope. So you should inject a `Map<String,Provider<Cloud>>`. Note that this works only since Guice 4.